# Reversal calculated workday without holidays in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a table with days of the month and I want to calculate remaining workdays like this:

1. DATA , DAY, DATA, REMAINING WORKDAYS
2. 01.04.2018, **Sunday**, "data" , **0**
3. 02.04.2018, Monday, "data" , 19
4. 03.04.2018, Tuesday, "data" , 18
5. 04.04.2018, Wednesday, "data" , 17
6. 05.04.2018, Thursday, "data" , 16
7. 06.04.2018, Friday, "data" , 15
8. 07.04.2018, **Saturday**, "data" , **0**
9. 08.04.2018, **Sunday**, "data" , **0**
10. 09.04.2018, Monday, "data" , 14

The formula in "Remaining workdays" has to be calculated automatically and when the day is Saturday and Sunday or Holiday have to jump to next workday.

Comment: How is remaining workdays 19 at 02/4/18? What is your working week? Are you excluding holidays? If you are including, what are the dates? UK for example would have 20  days incl holiday and 21 excl.

Comment: My bad, working days for April are 21, but in my country 6.04.2018 and 9.04.2018 are not working days...so for that in this case working days are 19

Comment: Why do your weekend days show `0` remaining workdays instead of `19` or `14` in your above table?

Comment: No need it to calculate in column Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A2,2)=6, WEEKDAY(A2,2)=7), 0,NETWORKDAYS(A2,EOMONTH(A2,0),$G$1:$G$2))
```

Where G1:G2 have your holiday dates. Drag formula down rows as required. See image.

A2 has your first date as a recognised date format.

[image: Data]

You say that 09 is a holiday so this;

09/04/2018  Monday   "data"     14

Should still be at 15.

Comment: OK , that is ok. Thanks a lot. I will change some and will be perfect. Thanks again